# Is there a way to edit parent relativePath with mvn

Tags: maven

Is there a command or mechanism that can edit all the child `pom.xml` files so that the parent `relativePath` tag gets edited or inserted for all the child modules?

Basically I have an aggregate `pom.xml`, and a separate parent `pom.xml`. The aggregator collects a set of independent git submodules, independently released, that are not setup to know about the aggregator nor the relative location of the parent, and I want a way to automatically apply the needed edits such that they do.

```
aggregator/
    - pom.xml
    - @parent/
        - pom.xml
    - @module1/
        - pom.xml
```

The modules reference the released versions of the parent, but I want to switch everything over to -SNAPSHOT (`versions:update-child-modules` handles this great), and to point the modules at the `relativePath` of the parent.

Currently I hand edit the files to insert `<relativePath>../parent</relativePath>` in each parent section.

The aggregator is optional for the projects, since it's coming long after the fact, so I can't really commit the hand edit changes to the module pom.xmls. This is why I want a dynamic mechanism for people that want to use the aggregator.

It may be I have to resort to a XML parser, but since I'm half way there without doing that it'd be nice if it could be avoided.

Comment: So you have a structure which your pom's represent which is not represented by you directory strucutre. Furthermore I don't understand the part about your aggregator ? If you have a parent for all childs than put that parent into the root of your structure that makes life easier...

Comment: The modules and the parent exist as standalone independent repos released independently. The aggregator is separate, for a convenient way to view the whole world.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: What is the contents of your aggregator pom.xml? If I understood it right (probably not) it is not needed at all...

Comment: Just a list of all the submodules, including the parent. There is no other place that the list exists, so in that sense it's needed. The "parent" is the parent in the "common base that children inherit details from" sense, but not in the "contains the list of child modules" sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question:**

No there doesn't seem to be a way using `mvn`.

I ended up using `python` to find the XML nodes in question, and then to make in-line edits to the `pom.xml` files.